# Why dont I see "loading experience" in google page insights API json file

Tags: api, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I am using google page insights to generate mobile performance data. For some URLs I am not seeing any "loading Experience" in the json file.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

I Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Emilio

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps not enough traffic to those pages?

Comment: agree with IronMan, What I have noticed for our domain is on last 28 days if impression for page is more than 250 from chrome browser that has sends usage statistics enabled get listed in API response.

Comment: Oh, I see, so the issue is the number of hits that site is getting. When it gets above a certain number we will start getting data through the API.